# How to transform a language specific string into string with python: str(ñ)

Tags: python, string, transform

Im writting some code to parse text, and in one of the variables, I can have text or integers, so in order to print it, I do str:

```
Variable=str(input)
```

It works fine, but if input contains a language-specific char: "ñ", it wont work, throwing the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xf1' in position 9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How to avoid this?

Comment: That's not language specific; it is called *unicode*, and a specific value of the `unicode` type that contains characters outside of the ASCII character set.

Comment: The question you have to ask yourself is *what encoding* to use instead of ASCII. See the http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html for details on how conversion works.

Comment: so if the rest of any of my scripts are working with ASCII compatible strings, and if I translate that string using any other encoder for it to work, they wont be compatible among each other?

Comment: thank you very much, going to study on it.

Comment: Look upon Unicode values as proper text objects, just like `datetime` objects represent specific date and time values properly, and `int` represent proper integer numbers. You can turn all of those to strings, but then you need to *encode* that information in some way.

Comment: Bytes in a string (characters) are really *encoded* text, but you need to pick one encoding and stick to it, just like you would need to pick a format to communicate date/time values in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I urge you to start reading up on Unicode first:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder

before you continue.

You need to *encode* `unicode()` values using a specific encoding; `str()` uses the default encoding ASCII, which fails for some of your values.

Explicit encoding can be done with the `unicode.encode()` method:

```
Variable = input.encode('utf8')
```

but you need to pick an encoding that works for your problem domain.

Comment: I believe it's also worth considering http://www.utf8everywhere.org/. In terms of the "Pragmatic Unicode" presentation, it replaces the "unicode sandwich" with a "utf-8 sandwich". Then in all the best cases, the external encoding is utf-8 anyway, so there's no actual bread. Python has not followed this strategy, so on Python it is not *necessarily* best to follow it either, but it's still worth knowing what the pros/cons are of Python's actual strategy, by comparison with another one that works.

Comment: Programatic unicode link you suggested is very, very good, and solves any unicode programs forward. thanks.

Comment: @SteveJessop: note that Python 3 switched to UTF-8 as the default codec where no explicit codec is supplied. Python 3.3 also switched away from the UCS2 / UCS4 compile-time switch and dynamically switches between Latin-1, UCS2 and UCS4 as required by the value to store Unicode characters as efficiently as required.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: well, as efficiently as is consistent with random-access, anyway :-) I've got nothing particularly against the variable-encoding string, but if it wasn't for the need for backward-compatibility with Python code that expects to use indexes then it probably wouldn't be necessary, strings could just be stored as utf-8 internally. The shame of it is that the code that's being supported is almost all incorrect: it was incorrect to assume you can (for example) truncate UTF-16 data indiscriminately, and it's *still* incorrect to assume you can truncate a sequence of code points.